# How to pass argument to a controller method while testing with RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails

Below are my controller methods which I am trying to test with RSpec

```
def login
    authorized_user = authenticate(params[:email], params[:password])
    if authorized_user
      # Creating a session if the User is Authorized
      session[:user_email] = authorized_user
      redirect_to(controller: 'home', action: 'details')
    else
      flash[:invalid] = 'Invalid Username or Password'
      redirect_to(action: 'signin')
    end
  end

def authenticate(email = '', password = '')
    url = 'http://localhost:8080/getUser/' + email
    response = RestClient.get(url)
    resp = JSON.parse(response)
    if resp[0]['id'] == 0
      return false  # If no user exists return false
    else
      return resp[0]['email']
    end
  end
```

Here I am trying to mock the RestClient.get() method and return a dummy email to the login method to set the session with.
Below is my spec file

```
it "mocks the api method checks the user with a Invalid email" do
      RestClient.should_receive(:get).and_return('[{"id":"0"}]')
      get :authenticate
      expect(response).to redirect_to '/signin'
    end
```

But here I need to pass email and password to the authenticate method. I am facing two problems here
1) How to pass the email and password to the authenticate method
2) When I call the authenticate method without the arguments like above I get an error like this

```
Failure/Error: url = 'http://localhost:8080/getUser/' + email

     TypeError:
       no implicit conversion of nil into String
```

So how can I mock the the RestClient.get() method and return some JSON as response by calling the authenticate method with some dummy email and password?

Comment: `get :authenticate('abc@gmail.com', '1234567890')` you can pass email and password like this.

Comment: @Gabbar Im getting this error 
syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting keyword_end
        get :authenticate('ssksmk@gmail','ss')

Answer (score 0):

In RSpec you can pass the params as a `Hash` in the `get` method

```
get :show, email: 'abc@gmail.com', password: '1234567890'
```

Comment: HI @mariowise. I tried this and its showing me this error

ArgumentError:
       unknown keywords: email, password

Comment: And this? `get :show, params: { email: 'abc@gmail.com', password: '1234567890' }`